# What determines the return order of Class.getMethods()?

Tags: java, reflection, runtime

This question is not looking for a solution to a problem but an explanation of why a problem may have arisen (or not!).

The [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods()) for `Class.getMethods()` say:

> The elements in the array returned are not sorted and are not in any particular order.

The thing is, this:  we’ve been using a neat little Java templating library called [JMTE](https://github.com/DJCordhose/jmte) for maybe a couple of years now, with no problems.  This uses JSTL-like syntax to inject model values into templates.  In particular, we’ve been using something like this to render a price:

```
${vendor.currency.symbol} ${order.amount}
```

The first of these translates to the the following:

```
vendor.getCurrency().getSymbol()
```

where `getCurrency()` returns a [java.util.Currency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html) object. Currency has two methods for getting the currency symbol - one that takes a specific Locale and one that uses the default.

[`public String getSymbol()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html#getSymbol())

[`public String getSymbol(Locale locale)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html#getSymbol(java.util.Locale))

For the last 18 months or so, everything has been running fine, with currency codes/symbols appearing in emails. Then 5 days ago, we started getting a random `IllegalArgumentException` thrown when trying to substitute `${vendor.currency.symbol}`

After a bit of debugging I found the cause, deep inside JMTE:

```
for (Method method : declaredMethods) {
    if (Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers())
        && (method.getName().equals("get" + suffix) ||   
            method.getName().equals("is" + suffix))) {
                value = method.invoke(o, (Object[]) null);
                ....
            }
}
```

i.e., Whether `getSymbol()` or `getSymbol(Locale)` was called is completely at the mercy of the return order of `Class.getMethods()` (*not in any particular order*).  I added a test to ensure the method has 0 parameters and my problem was solved.

Now, by a strange coincidence, someone else happened to submit an [identical fix](https://github.com/DJCordhose/jmte/pull/5) on the very same day that we first observed this behaviour.

What’s puzzling is that this code has been running for 18 months with no problems, then all of a sudden, this behaviour appears.

When I created a test case it failed roughly 50% of the time, as one would expect (there are 2 matching methods, returned in no particular order), so I'm puzzled (amazed) it worked for 18 months and 10^5 executions. (It's conceivable, but unlikely, that it has failed but succeeded on subsequent retries).

**Purely out of curiosity**, I’m wondering if there’s anything in the Java runtime that might cause this latent behaviour to suddenly appear.  It’s even more puzzling that a fix for this behaviour should be provided by someone else on the same day for a project that is mature and stable - suggesting perhaps that the same latent behaviour suddenly realised itself elsewhere.

So, the question is: does anyone know what factors might influence the order of the methods returned by `Class.getMethods()`?

Answer (score 2):

The relevant Java code that can be seen from `getMethods()` shows a lot of checking for cached data, but the final say is up to this implementation:

`private native Method[] getDeclaredMethods0(boolean publicOnly);`

Therefore it's VM dependent, and a very poor idea to trust the order simply because "it was the same one a lot of times".

The caching affects it certainly, since if it's fetched correctly the first time, it'll work for the subsequent times as well unless the cache is cleared (there's some soft reference business and such going on).

Comment: That kind of fits in with my findings: my test case was running on my local machine with plain old (Oracle) JDK 7 VM, but the production code was running on Google App Engine, where I assume they have plenty of caching magic that just happened to work in our favour all this time.

Comment: the better question is if the documentation flat out says it may not return in the same order every time, why were you trusting that it would

Comment: @MarshallTigerus He wasn't. The developers of the framework were.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus I didn't - it was a third party library. In fairness, the developers were probably not assuming fixed return order but (I'm guessing) assuming the developer would be calling only no-arg methods on bean-like objects.